# JavaScript array sort-function for both numeric and alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I need to sort an array that looks like this:

```
var array = new Array();<br />
array[0]="201206031245 firstitem";<br />
array[1]="201206020800 seconditem";<br />
array[2]="201206040604 itemthree";<br />
array[3]="201206031345 lastitem";<br />
```

How would I sort this numerically and descending?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, when you get so many answers in couple minutes, it usually says, you didn't put a little effort solving it yourself.

Comment: Apologies for the simple question--I did put effort into this, and am relatively novice with arrays.  Sounds stupid for a JavaScript developer but it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `.sort()` will by default do an alphanumeric sort, for your data it will work numerically because your array elements all start with numbers that follow a strict date/time format with the same number of digits. `.sort()` will sort *ascending* though. You could provide your own comparison function to sort *descending*, or you could just reverse the results:

```
array.sort().reverse()
```

For more information about how `.sort()` works, e.g., to provide your own comparison function, have a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!  Looking in retrospect I realize I didn't need to be so intent on the numerical sort function.  This works well!  Apologies for the simple question, but I appreciate the answer--it's the solution to a lot of work!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). It will sort alphabetical, but as long as your numbers have the same number of digits that's perfectly OK.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to call [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on your Array:

```
array.sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = array.sort(function(a,b){ return a.split(' ')[0] < b.split(' ')[0]})
```

Comment: A sort comparison function needs to return a negative value, a positive value or zero, not a boolean value.